# Custom UITabBarController - using a UIToolBar with UISegmentedcontrol as Tab Bar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

My customer wants a design-change, but I just can't figure out how to do this!

The app currently have a `UITabBarController` shifting between some `UINavigationController`'s. My customer wants to use a `UIToolBar` with a `UISegmentedControl` shifting between the controllers instead.

I want to keep the `UITabBarController`, because that takes care of everything regarding loading and shifting views, but I want the `UIToolBar` to act as the `UITabBar` instead of the `UITabBar`!

I have allready figured out that I will need a custom `UITabBarController` and possibly a custom `UIToolBar` as well.

But I have absolutely no idea of where to start, so it would be great if somebody could give me a pointer as to where to start.

[Top part to act as bottom part. http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/14763142/1g5g1s.Skjermbilde%202010-06-25%20kl.%2012.24.59.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/14763142/1g5g1s.Skjermbilde%202010-06-25%20kl.%2012.24.59.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to have a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the screen that has a `UISegmentedControl` that replaces pressing `UITabBarItem`'s to switch between different views and view controllers? Assuming this is true I'd start with a custom `UIToolbar` class, say `SegmentedControlToolbar` that mirrors the basic behaviour of `UITabBarController` and `UITabBar` to add items to a segmented control, attach view controllers to each segment, and finally handle presses for each segmented control change to actually switch views.

Comment: This turned out great in the end, I hid the `UITabBar` under the `UIToolBar`, and hooked up a couple of selectors. Thank you!

Comment: Details on how to hide the UITabBar and set up the selectors would be greatly appreciated.